# Get the app launch parameters by process id in Mac OS X

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript

I know the Unix "ps" command do it, but it and similar commands show command line only for unix style processes. for example if I double click a png file in Finder, the Preview.app opens that png file. if I exec the ps command for pid of Preview.app the result will be:

```
ps -p 556

PID TTY           TIME CMD
556 ??         0:45.38 /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview
```

As be seen there is no command line (png file)

Also this code and other solutions based on sysctl acts as ps command:

```
   int mib[4] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0 };
   unsigned long buffer_size;
   sysctl(mib, 4, NULL, &buffer_size, NULL, 0);

   struct kinfo_proc *result = (kinfo_proc *)malloc(buffer_size);
   sysctl(mib, 4, result, &buffer_size, NULL, 0);

   int num_procs = buffer_size / sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);
   for (int i = 0; i < num_procs; i++) {
       struct kinfo_proc *pproc = result + i;
       int mib[3] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_PROCARGS, pid_of(pproc) }; 
       char *proc_argv;
       unsigned long argv_len;
       sysctl(mib, 3, NULL, &argv_len, NULL, 0);
       proc_argv = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * argv_len);
       sysctl(mib, 3, proc_argv, &argv_len, NULL, 0);
       fwrite(proc_argv, sizeof(char), argv_len, stdout);
       printf("\n");
       free(proc_argv);
   }
```

Is there a way to access launch params for programs run by Finder?

Comment: "there is no command line" Correct. The document is opened by sending Preview an Apple event.

Comment: Since it is a Finder thing, you can get its selection - what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @red_menace I have a proxy app, I want exec the run app by my app, first kill the app run by Finder and run it by my app and pass params.

Comment: @Willeke Ok, Looks like you're right

Comment: Instead of trying to figure out what has already been launched, another option would be to set your application to be the default for the particular files or file type so that it gets them first.

Comment: @red_menace I can not do it for some reasons.

Comment: Have you tried `KERN_PROCARGS2`?

Comment: works like a charm, but excuse my  laziness... any standard way to convert the null punctuated buffer simply into an NSArray of NSStrings, or some other higher level thing?